# Android 4.1.2 permission BROADCAST_SMS

Tags: android, permissions, sms

I've been trying to implement an application which sends and receives fake sms on my device (Samsung Galaxy S2, Android 4.1.2). I found an example of such application here: 
http://blog.dev001.net/post/14085892020/android-generate-incoming-sms-from-within-your
I copy-pasted it and ran on my device. Nothing happened and I found in logs that BROADCAST_SMS permission was system. I made the app system using Titanium Backup, restart my device and ran the app again. And nothing happened again. I got the same exception that my app had no rights to use BROADCAST_SMS permission. Then I read that I should specify `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in manifest. When I added it I failed to run my app using Intellij Idea 14:
`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]`
I tried to install generated by Idea app but got exception: `Package has no signatures that match those in shared user android.uid.system; ignoring!`

So I have several questions:
1. How is it possible to install unsigned app with `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in manifest?
2. Will my app be able to use BROADCAST_SMS permission if I make it system using  Titanium Backup or other trick?
3. Is there any other way to force the app work on my device?

I have seen applications which imitate sms incoming. But they all write to inbox directly. I need an application which makes other applications believe that new sms is coming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "How is it possible to install unsigned app with android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in manifest?" -- that should not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use shareduserid your app must have the same signature as all other apps using this uid. Installing the app on /system partition or even giving it priv-app status is not sufficient.

And btw the permission is of level "signature" anyway (not signatureOrSystem) so the only way you can be granted the permission is if your app uses the same signature as the android framework. In other words, you have to make a custom platform build and flash your phone with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you install/build Android from AOSP, a test key is used to sign all the apps. You can use this key to sign your app and install it as a system app. This works great for testing; obviously not going to be an option for something you want to distribute.